# Spring 4 Framework Internationalization not identify message from resource properties file with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

Using new spring version, with thymeleaf, is not my specialty, with gradle,
I try a lot ways change position files and configurations of basename and still receiving ??welcome.message_**?? on template result.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

[...]

@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        String[] resources= {"/WEB-INF/locale/messages", "WEB-INF/locale/messages", "locale/messages", "i18n", "locale"};
        messageSource.setBasenames(resources);
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

@Bean 
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    return localeChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver(){
    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver=new SessionLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pt","BR"));
    return localeResolver;
}

public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Template:

`<h1 th:text="#{welcome.message}">Welcome!</h1>`

have 2 properties on `src/java/webapp/WEB-INF/local/messages.properties` and `src/java/webapp/WEB-INF/local/messages_pt_BR.properties`

github project: https://github.com/brunoguerra/springtutorial/tree/master/web-scure-jpa

Thanks for any ideia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After walk around I found samples from spring-projects on [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples). The solution is very simple, just define `public MessageSource messageSource()` on your MVC configurer instead `public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource()` on application configurer.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

[...]

@Bean    
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bean name should be **messageSource**
We can do it either

```
@Bean(name ="messageSource")
public MessageSource anyName() {}
```

Or

```
public MessageSource messageSource() {}
```